# How do I create a directory in a Docker container that won't start?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a Docker container (not image) that crashes when I try to start it.  The Docker logs show that it is failing because and Apache2 conf file can't find a directory (/var/www/html/log/ - this is the result of me trying to get SSL setup and forgot to create this directory after I referenced it in the 000-default.conf file and restarted Apache).

How do I create this directory in the container without having to start the container itself?

Comment: Typically the answer is to destroy the container and create a new one from a known good state. If you find yourself in a situation where this is undesirable, then you're likely treating your container as a pet instead of cattle.

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was copy the .conf file to the host, make a very minor tweak and copy it back into the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4.5 options that comes to my mind:

- You can rebuild the image and set up the directory while doing it.
- You can attach a volume while starting the image, but in this case your changes will remain in your disk and not in your container.
- You can run the image overriding the entry point with --entrypoint="bash" or something. You need to do it with `-ti` flag so that it begins in interactive mode. Then make your changes and run `docker commit -p <container> <image:tag>` -p pauses container while commiting. I recommend this unless it absolutely needs to be running.
- I am not sure if this one works so I give half point :P but if it does this would be the fastest option actually. You can start the container in interactive mode with `docker start -i container` which would attach a terminal. And if you have time until container exits or read that part of configuration, you can create the folder.
- Ah finally, I have just remembered, you should be able to move files and folders from your file system to container using `docker cp [container:]<source> [container:]<destination>` even while container is not running.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions... I went with 5.  Copied the 000-default.conf file over, made changes, and copied it back into the container.  Container starts OK now.

Comment: You may want to commit your image in any case.

Comment: BTW docker start will allow -i but not -ti.

Comment: Actually no, rather than commiting, I think it is better practice to use volumes for configuration stuff.

Comment: I'm a newb to containers so will look into the use of volumes.  I had a major panic yesterday when I committed the container, fired up another one of the resulting image and could not find any of my data... of course it is in a data volume ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you're using a base Docker image for Apache (for example,  httpd/2.4/Dockerfile), it *should* already have "/var/www/html/log".

SUGGESTION 1: Please make sure you're starting with a "good" base image.

SUGGESTION 2: Add "mkdir -p /var/www/html/log" to your Dockerfile, and rebuild the image.

I'm not sure how you're using your image - what you want the image to contain *besides* Apache - but:

SUGGESTION 3: Google for a simple tutorial that matches your use case, and see what steps you might be "missing".  For example: [Dockerize your Laravel Application](https://runnable.com/docker/php/dockerize-your-laravel-application)